# Approach for Problems which appeared in 101 Hack June Challenge contest

Tags: algorithm, math

I gave 101 Hack June Challenge contest but there were two problems which I wasn't able to solve. Can anyone give me some hint on how to approach these two questions:

Q1. **Assignment Problem**

Calvin has a math assignment at school where he has to evaluate a lot of expressions. Calvin decides to not to waste much of his time. There are ‘M’ expressions overall. By looking at Susie’s answers, Calvin has figured that the answers to all questions form a non decreasing sequence.

He decides that all his answers are going to be between 1 and ‘N’ (inclusive). He fills his answer sheet with a random non-decreasing sequence of length ‘M’ where each element is between 1 and ‘N’.

Here is the part where the real problem starts for Calvin. He does not want to choose a large value of N, because, he will have a lot of options to choose from. Also, if he chooses a very small value of N, a lot of answers would become equal and the teacher will become suspicious.

If x = max1 ≤ i ≤ N (frequency (i)), frequency (i) being the number of times i occurs in the sequence of ‘M’ values he picked. Calvin wants to find out expected value of x. Help him solve the problem.

For example, if M = 3 & N = 3, the possible sequences are:

```
1 1 1 (x = 3)
1 1 2 (x = 2)
1 1 3 (x = 2)
1 2 2 (x = 2)
1 2 3 (x = 1)
1 3 3 (x = 2)
2 2 2 (x = 3)
2 2 3 (x = 2)
2 3 3 (x = 2)
3 3 3 (x = 3)

expected value of x = 2.2
```

Input Format

The first line contains an integer T which refers to the number of test cases. T lines follow, each containing 2 numbers, M and N for the corresponding test cases.

Constraints

```
T ≤ 15
1 ≤ M ≤ 250
1 ≤ N ≤ 10^9
```

Output Format

Output T lines, each containing answer to the corresponding test case. Error of upto 10^-3 is allowed.

Sample Input

```
4
1 5
3 3
2 9
9 6
```

Sample Output

```
1.0000000000
2.2000000000
1.2000000000
4.3146853147
```

Q2. **GCD mocktail**

The Rebel Alliance and the Galactic Empire are engaged in an epic battle in the skies above Endor. The grand setup has d-dimensional board with each dimension of length ‘N’, (i.e) N x N… (d times). Each cell (i1, i2, …id) has the gcd (i1, i2, …id) written on it.

Now, the game begins. A random integer L is chosen and the first person to sum up the Lth power of each number modulo 30000001 wins the game.

Rebel Alliance needs some help and pings you. If they win, you get a million dollars for it. Can you help?

Input Format

There are several test cases. The first line contains the number of test cases T. Then T test cases follow. Each test case is given in the following format.
N and d are given in the first Line.
Q is given in the second line.
Each of the next Q lines contain an integer L.

Constraints

```
0 <= T <= 10
1 <= N <= 107
1 <= d <= 1000
0 <= L <= 100
0 <= Q <= 50
```

Output Format

For each test case, output Q lines, indicating the answer.

Sample Input

```
3
3 2
4
0
1
2
3
5 1
3
0
1
2
6 3
2
2
3
```

Sample Output

```
9
12
20
42
5
15
55
421
975
```

This are links to problems on website:

Q1. https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101june13/challenges/assignment

Q2. https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101june13/challenges/gcd-mocktail

The contest has ended, so I guess it's not cheating by asking some help on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hackerrank have posted the solution to assignment at https://www.hackerrank.com/blog/101hack-editorial-assignment-problem

Answer (score 1):

For Q2:

Let's start by counting how many times each value appears in such an array:

1 - appears whenever the positions are coprime. This is hard to count directly, so let's leave it out for now.

2 - appears when all the positions are a multiple of 2. How many combinations of numbers from `[1, N]` are all multiples of 2, allowing repeats? There are `N / 2` possibilities for the first value, and as many for all of the other `d` values, so `(N / 2)^d` possibilities. However, we have also counted those that are all a LARGER multiple, which would give a larger GCD. So we must subtract those formed from nothing but larger multiples, that is `(N / 4)^d + (N / 6)^d + ...`

`k <= N` - can be deduced the same as above. Let `num(k)` be this value.

Therefore, 1 will appear `N^d - num(2) - num(3) - ...` times.

So you have to compute the sum:

```
S = num(1) + num(2) * 2^L + num(3) * 3^L + ...
```

This gives an `O(N^2 * L)` or `O(N^2 log L)` solution if you implement it directly, which is too slow, since `N` can go up to `10^7`. We have to do a lot better.

Let's write out `S`:

```
S =   N^d - num(2) - num(3) - ...
    + num(2) * 2^L + num(3) * 3^L + ...
  = N^d + num(2)(2^L - 1) + num(3)(3^L - 1) + ...
  = N^d + [(N / 2)^d - (N / 4)^d - ...](2^L - 1) 
        + [(N / 3)^d - (N / 6)^d - ...](3^L - 1)
        + [(N / 4)^d - (N / 8)^d - ...](4^L - 1)
        + ...
```

A lot of terms repeat themselves, but so far I'm not sure where to go from here. I'll leave this up in case it helps anyone take it further and I'll delete it if someone posts a complete solution.

Comment: +1: I think this approach might be a lot faster than you predict (e.g. more like O(nlogn)) because the number of terms you have to subtract rapidly decreases as the gcd increases.  However, I think the formula might be slightly wrong and should be more like `num(2)=(N/2)^d-num(4)-num(6)-...`

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz - even `O(n log n)` would be too slow I think, for `n = 10^7`. Plus, there is also the cost of exponentiation. The formula is correct as I wrote it. If you write it like you suggest, you will subtract things multiple times: for example, you will subtract `(N / 12)^d` twice. You must subtract the appropriate multiples, not the number of times each value appears. I am thinking there has to be a solution involving a `O(sqrt n)` or `O(log n)` factor.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1, imagine if you knew the function `f(N, M, K)` giving you the # of ways that a non-decreasing sequence of `M` integers in the range `1` to `N` could have at most `K` repeated.  Then `f(N, M, K) - f(N, M, K-1)` gives you the number that have exactly `K` repeated.  And now we get the exact distribution, giving us the exact answer.

Now `f(N, M, K)` obviously is `0` if `0 = K` and `0 < M`.  And `f(N, 0, 0)` is trivially `1`.  (There is only one empty set.)  Add in the fact that `f(N, M, K) = f(N, M, K-1) + f(N-1, M-K, K)` and we're all set to solve with dynamic programming.  (The main challenge is that you're probably going to run out of floating point range if `N` is a billion, and `M` is 250...)

---

I'd have to think about Q2.  I have an idea how to do it, but it isn't quite as simple for me.